# Increment a concatenate formula with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation, increment

I don't find a good solution to automatically increment a concatenate formula starting at row 2 and finishing at row 50.

I already managed to set the concatenate formula in the second row and 10th column with this.

```
var formula2 = 'CONCATENATE(C1;" - ";D1)'

sheet.getRange(2,10).setFormula(formula2)
```

How should I do now to increment it automatically from 2 to 50 in the E column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet.getRange(2,10).setFormula(formula2)
```

#### To:

```
sheet.getRange("E2:E50").setFormula(formula2);
```

- If you want to put `CONCATENATE(C2;" - ";D2)` to the cell "E2", please modify `var formula2 = 'CONCATENATE(C1;" - ";D1)'` to `var formula2 = 'CONCATENATE(C2;" - ";D2)'`.

#### Reference:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))

Comment: Working perfectly ! Thanks

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I still have a question. In you solution, you give me a great advice when the number of rows is known. But what if the number of rows is undefined ?

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, about your new question of `what if the number of rows is undefined ?`, I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about your goal of your new question? By correctly understand about your new question, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize for this. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: No problem ! Assuming I have a firstname in A1 and a lastname in B1, I want my concatenate function to make it "firstname lastname" in C1. This works with the above. But my columns "firstname" and "lastname" autofill when I have a new user on my app and I want my concatenate function to iterate until last row having firstname and lastname. Is it better ?

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for replying. From your replying, for example, `sheet.getRange("C1:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).setFormula('CONCATENATE(A1;" - ";B1)')` is the result you expect? If I misunderstood your new goal, I apologize again.

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks a lot. I was trying with "&" as I saw on other solutions but it works great with the "+".

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your new issue was also resolved. Thank you, too.